# keyof behavior for call signature vs generic constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a call signature for an undocumented API as follows:

```js
// MyLib.d.ts documents MyLib
interface GetV<KV = {[K: string]: any}> {
   <K extends keyof KV>(options:{ field: K }): KV[K];
}

export function getV : GetV;
```

I can use it like this:

```js
import * as MyLib from 'Root/MyLIb';

const x : any = MyLib.getV(options:{ field: 'foo' });
```

That works, but I have a lot of SpecificTypeInformation about the fields so I wanted a way to provide those specifics get more specific answer for that specific fields.

Modify MyLib.d.ts as:

```js
// MyLib.d.ts documents MyLib
interface GetV<KV = {[K: string]: any}> {
   <SUBKV extends KV = KV, K extends keyof KV=keyof KV>(options:{ field: K }): SUBKV[K];
}

export function getV : GetV;
```

then use it as:

```js
import * as MyLib from 'Root/MyLIb';

type SpecificTypeInformation = { foo: 'bar'; goo: 'baz' };

// @ts-expect-error expects 'bar'|'baz'
const x : 'bar' = MyLib.getV<SpecificTypeInformation>({ field: 'foo' });
```

but unfortunately, X is still assigned `'bar'|'baz'`;

I can get it to work as desired by constraining getV like this:

```js
import * as MyLib from 'Root/MyLIb';

type SpecificTypeInformation = { foo: 'bar'; goo: 'baz' };

const x : 'bar' = (MyLib.getV as MyLib.GetV<SpecificTypeInformation>)({ field: 'foo' });
```

But why do I have to do that? I didn't want to export GetV but it's more the usage of the API that becomes obtuse.

Is this a bug or am I stuck with this?

Edit: i had trouble reproducing this until i add the paramter via 'options'!! The playground link shows it more clearly

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&esModuleInterop=false&preserveConstEnums=true&importHelpers=true&target=7&jsx=0&module=2&pretty=true&ts=4.9.5&noUnusedLocals=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAngGQJYCMCMSA3gFDFLlJbAAuEATgGYLIDiE1AagDwDSHSEAB61gAEyhEkAbR4AuJFGp0qAcwC68xcuAqkAXyQBeSTM1LVGheZ36AfCQqOkvAcIhiJAawhoA9gyQ+WwAKXxhqLF9gKHlCJAYsCAAbUXkefQBKJDSOGTUAbjIKPVJHIRhfOmokUQh4JJA6ZHgoxSQVdg55Nk58pGIS4lBIWGZUTFwAJiJiAHpZ-tcKqsoaeiZEJB7uPlcRcRM5K211eRBgNH0jQ7MTy3PLvXsip2cAZQBVACF+IX2JOKmY4WM4XK7GPgAGkCe3cB28fgCnx+1wR-iQyI4ITCEVasXiiRSaUy2Qx31yPAKL0WxVKFHKlWqtXqjWarWqHU43U6fQGpCG4GgcE26GwOAAzDN5gosGAsA06EhqL5xmKCDgAK7VbaUCQMqoQUT9an66pUWiMMbbXi-NweG7AnSWLSqcEOl1O26up4OV7OdJ-OFeHzooKhcKRaL4hLJVIwvRZHJ5QqOQZlQTLJl1BVs6Iczrc3r9QbUNAwZBvcvwLAJeAAFTLEAAksAGCrjHE2755AByHCNHt9FS+btIPsgABePb0hWILTzSAAbgRjKLcHgAHScjjBTuEuM9rs9zKzuYLYAqgBWvkuAForPKkuQQEkn4uXxroEh0dQABbIWA6hrLB4CVRt+nnNpF2mXt+zoY9VwmHBJi3TouErIDawbcsWzbEI91jXsjxPY1IPzThJUQsVxVQzgkBACQ1wlDdrQw6ssMbXDfFsOd2SXSVYIHa5t3FXcCUIsdiITfIgA)

this was motivated enough to do is also in vscode [via codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-d9yjsd?file=/app/app.ts) . My IDE is webstorm or Emacs

Comment: Ideally code here would be a [mre] that we could paste into our own IDEs and quickly get started.  Right now my IDE doesn't know what `Values`, `SpecificTypeInformation`, etc. are.  Could you [edit] so that when someone copies and pastes your code the only issues they are faced with are the ones you are asking about?

Comment: ok, playground link added @jcalz

Comment: As for your question: it's not a TS bug, but a missing feature.  There's currently no support for *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242); see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) and its answer for more info.  All you can do is work around it.  Perhaps you can wrap the function and use currying as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRPbXm)?  Or just do what you're doing.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: gtk about that issue.  Whichever way I'll go it will need to prioritize imports to the original api being the same as well as compiled js looking the same